# Lifecycle callback order with "don't keep activities" mode

Tags: android, android-activity, activity-lifecycle

I'm trying to find any information about guaranteed lifecycle callbacks order (interested only in onCreate, onResume, onPause) for the following scenario:

1. Don't keep activities mode is enabled.
2. Activity A starts Activity B (dialog activity) and becomes partially obscured.
3. User presses Home button.
4. Both activities are destroyed.
5. User navigates back to app.

So, what is the guaranteed lifecycle callbacks execution order after steps (3), (5)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So, what is the guaranteed lifecycle callbacks execution order after steps (3), (5)?

After step 3:

- `onStop()` is guaranteed to be called
- `onDestroy()` is **not** guaranteed.

After step 5:

- `onCreate()`
- `onStart()`
- `onRestoreInstanceState()`
- `onResume()`

All of these are guaranteed to be called.

---

I've logged lifecycle callbacks, and here's the output.

### Activity A starts Activity B

- A pause
- B create
- B start
- B resume
- A saveInstanceState

### Home button pressed

- B pause
- A stop
- B saveInstanceState

### User navigates back to app

- A create
- A start
- A restoreInstanceState
- A resume
- A pause
- B start
- B resume

**Note:**

- ActivityB has `Theme.AppCompat.Dialog` as theme
- `Don't keep activities` mode is turned on
- Running on Nexus 4 emulator, API 21

Comment: This is for one activity. Could you kindly describe order for A, B?

Comment: Why won't create a project, log lifecycle callbacks and see? What's the reasoning behind that?

Comment: And how to know if obtained order is guaranteed?

Comment: Which exact order you need to have guarantee on?

Comment: I need guaranteed order of resume and pause callbacks.

Comment: All callbacks within **"User navigates back to app"** are stable and consistent.